# Storyboard referencing issue of view controller

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, storyboard

[image]

[image]

i was working on this project, everything was working fine. from three days i'm facing this issue all of my storyboards are showing this error. existing outlets are yellow and i couldn't add any new outlet. like in this chatViewController i added a new ibaction but it's not showing, it's working fine with existing iboutlets and actions but new outlets and ibaction are not adding. I'm unable to add new functionalities.
can anyone help me resolving this issue?

Comment: Did you change the storyboard/view controller name?

Comment: no i didn't, i only an extension for notification as mentioned in one signal documentation

Comment: Clear derived data, Force quit xcode and Simulator. That might help you.

Answer (score 0):

try removing all the actions and make sure if it's a button its set to "Action" and if it's a label it's set to "view".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).